# EF migration creates unnecessary column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to ASP.NET Framework and I've got an issue with generating tables for my models.

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class ServiceModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
}
```

And it generates this code for the migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ServiceModel",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Duration = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                EmployeeModelId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
            },...
```

As you can see there is a 4th column made for another model that is referencing to this model, but this reference is unwanted. I just want it to be exact as the model, but I don't think that modifying the migration file is a good idea.

Here is the referenced `EmployeeModel` class:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceModel> AvailableServices { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftEnd { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to keep the `AvailableServices` as a `List<ServiceModel>` instead of making it a list of Id's, but if it's the only way I'll go with it.

Comment: How else are you going to create the relation specified by `Employee.AvailableServices`? Since it's a `1-Many`, you do that by adding `EmployeeId` to `Service`. If it was `Many-Many` you'd need a many-to-many table

Comment: `Service` is meant to be added to other class alongside with `Employee`, this connection is  only for veryfing if `Employee` is able to execute the `Service`. It's just my wrong way of thinking the models for this solution.

Comment: They are entities, not models. Which correspond (loosely) to tables. In the end you're designing tables in a database and need to come up with a good relational design. ORMs attempt to hide this, but in the end it's the database design that's used to store the data and execute the queries. If the `Service` rows can be related to multiple other tables, you need one join table for each relation.

Comment: [EF Core 6 can hide this relation table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#scaffolding-many-to-many-relationships), but older versions need it to appear as an explicit class, eg `EmployeeServices`.

Answer (score -1):

I just realized that I wanted to make a column that holds list of models, which is not a brilliant idea...